# Doctrine orderBy on SUM() field with alias

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I am trying to do a simple query in doctrine but struggling.

```
$query->select(array(
    'app_title' => 'u.title',
    'user_name' => 'u.user_name',
    'first_used' => 'MIN(u.creation_time)',
    'last_used' => 'MAX(u.stop_time)',
    'total_usage' => 'SUM(u.stream_seconds)',
))
->from(self::USAGE_TABLE, 'u')
->orderBy('total_usage', 'DESC');
```

Obviously I get an error about the column name not being known because Doctrine is using it's own aliases (sclr4).

However, if I try and order by the actual value; SUM(u.stream_seconds), then I get an unexpected bracket in the order by clause, I'm pretty sure SQL doesnt support this.

So, I am simply trying to put data in a table and handle the sorting of the columns. This seems so simple, how do I do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 28):

1. You can orderBy the SUM result field by list it in query projection by aliasing result using `AS`.
2. If you want to use an aggregate function such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, you have to use `GROUP BY`.

Try simmilar to this, which works perfectly for me (BTW instead of associative array in `select` method):

```
$q = $this->em()->createQueryBuilder();

$q->select(['product.id', 'product.title'])
  ->addSelect('SUM(product.price) AS HIDDEN stat_sum_realised')
  ->from('ModuleAdmin\Entity\ProductEntity', 'product')
  ->groupBy('product.id');

$q->orderBy('stat_sum_realised', 'DESC');
```

Aggregate functions are detailed here (for e.x. for MySQL):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

As of Doctrine ORM 2.3, you can also use the `HIDDEN` keyword, which will avoid (in this case) `stat_sum_realised` from getting hydrated into your resultset.

Comment: This helps thanks, now I only get a problem when I start using setFirstResult for the pagination..
"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sclr4 DESC) AS doctrine_rownum ..." obviously gives "Invalid column name 'sclr4'." but I can't seem to work out how to stop it!

Comment: @YorkshireDeveloper Did you ever figure out why you got that "Invalid column name 'sclr4'" exception? I'm having the same issue.